# Understanding React.FC in Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I've been trying to understand how the React.FC type works and tried multiple things this being the only one that works:

```
import React from 'react'
    
    type iProps<P = {}> = {
        (props: P): React.ReactElement<any, any>
    }
    
    interface IPropsTest {
        name: string,
        age: number
    }
    
    const MyComponent: iProps<IPropsTest> = ({ name, age }) => {
        return <div>{name} {age}</div>
    }
```

Could someone explain this part

```
type iProps<P = {}> = {
    (props: P): React.ReactElement<any, any>
}
```

Why do I need `<P = {}>` and why do I have to put `(props: P)`

Comment: what are you trying to do? Your are not even using the `FC` type here

Comment: Do you conceptually understand Typescript generics? If not, start there.

Answer (score 1):

## What is `P = {}`

This is a generic default. If the generic argument is not provided then `P` is assumed to be `{}`.

## Why do I have to put `(props: P)`

This means the function can be expected to be called with one argument of type `P`.